# CRUD with just GETs and POSTs

Tags: backbone.js, crud

Instead of the default sync method, with DELETEs, PUTs &c, I'll have to use GETs and POSTs to do the CRUD operations. Is there a more elegant approach to this problem than overriding save(), fetch() and other methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backbone has built in support for such things through [`emulateHTTP`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateHTTP):

> **emulateHTTP** `Backbone.emulateHTTP = true`
>
> If you want to work with a legacy web server that doesn't support Backbones's default REST/HTTP approach, you may choose to turn on `Backbone.emulateHTTP`. Setting this option will fake `PUT` and `DELETE` requests with a HTTP `POST`, setting the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header with the true method. If `emulateJSON` is also on, the true method will be passed as an additional `_method` parameter.
>
> ```
> Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
>
> model.save();  // POST to "/collection/id", with "_method=PUT" + header.
> ```

So set `Backbone.emulateHTTP` to `true` and adjust your server-side code to look at the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header to see what POST requests are supposed to mean.